# Simple bitmasking assistance

Tags: php, bit

I have the following flags:

```
- edit profile => 1
- update coupon => 2
- update news articles => 4
```

I want to understand how can I set and check the bit mask for all the three flags (that is, the user has access to all 3 bit masks).

- Do we add all the bits together?
- What about just having access to 2?

Not quite sure what to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a user to have all the permissions then `or` the bits.

e.g.

```
$permission_bitmask = $edit_profile | $update_coupon | $update_news_articles;
```

For just two of the permissions, it's the same idea.

```
$permission_bitmask = $edit_profile | $update_coupon;
```

To check the bitmask, and the bitmask with your desired bit.

```
$has_edit_profile = ($edit_profile & $permission_bitmask) !== 0;
```

Comment: @RyanVincent If you are only checking one bit at a time then it doesn't matter. If you want to compare two bit-masks with multiple bits (e.g. check this user has at least this bitmask) then yes you would need to compare the `and`ed values to the desired minimum bitmask.